# ElasticSearch Golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch

Is it possible to identify multiple hosts with [elastigo](https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo)? I can't seem to find anything specific to that. Anyone using [elastigo](https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo) in a PROD setting? I would really like to attempt using a go based app for our web services, but we have a requirement with ElasticSearch, Redis and possibly a few others.  Just not sure that the drivers for go are ready yet.

Any suggestions / info would be appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[elastigo](https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo) is working very well in a production setting for us. As far as detecting 'hosts' my best suggestion is to read the elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html) which describes their cluster management scheme - most of that work is handled by elasticsearch itself. In our (rather straightforward) usage I've never had to think about anything beyond the server host address:port - nodes self-connect to a named cluster when brought online (with proper configuration parameters) and load balancing is handled within elasticsearch itself.

Comment: Thanks @snwight I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

My answer could be a bit late, but still... I have recently (mid 2016) chosen [olivere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) over [elastigo](https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo) as Elasticsearch Go client for our production application.

Reasons for the choice were:

- [*olivere/elastic*](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/graphs/commit-activity) is under active development for the last year, while [*elastigo*](https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo/graphs/commit-activity) gets updated less and less regularly
- As of 2016, developers recommend *olivere/elastic* more on the Internet

I would highly recommend you to have a look at *olivere/elastic* if you haven't made decision yet. Also there is a blog post [Working With Elasticsearch in Go](https://codewithyury.com/working-with-elasticsearch-in-go), which demonstrates on example how to use *olivere/elastic* to index and search documents. (In case you want to get a flavour of how the code looks like.)